# How to retain excel cell format when IF statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with data like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5rVn.png). There are hundreds of rows.

I have a different sheet that shows the same data provided an IF condition is satisfied, ex. "=IF(Language="English", "Object", "")". When I do this, the cells appear without their original unique formatting (no different font size, color, line break) like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meyg8.png). I want it to appear like the original formatting, which can be done with copy pasting the values, but I want to keep the IF statement coded so that when the original Object and Language directory is updated the new sheet reflects the change automatically without me having to manually copy paste every time.

Comment: I think you can only achieve this with VBA code. Would a VBA code solution work for you? Something like this: [How to copy source formatting of the lookup cell when using Vlookup in Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5053-excel-vlookup-copy-formatting.html)